# how to import excel file with laravel maatwebsite?

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import a xls file which contains a date formula:

> =DIA.LAB.INTL(FIN.MES(FECHA(C4;C3;1);-1);1)

But, i got this error:

> PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception in Cell.php line 293:
>   Sheet1!D7 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ','

I see that error is the comma but this comma does not exist in the formula.

did i missing something?

Comment: Such problems are usually caused by using the wrong delimiter (eg. `;` instead of `,`). Try changing your delimiter. See if any of these answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/31512333/2939061 http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217453/2939061 help.

Comment: Thanks!!, I'll try and then let you know if it works

Answer (score 1):

The formula is affected by your Spanish regional settings. The formula is actually

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(EOMONTH(DATE(C4,C3,1),-1),1)
```

that contains comma. MS Excel always store the formula using English regional settings.

Your formula is correct, but most probably PHPExcel might not recognize `DIA.LAB.INTL` function.
You can try to change your regional settings and see if the error persist.